# Continuous Integration with .Net Core App and Database Project (VS2017)

Tags: asp.net-core, continuous-integration, azure-devops, visual-studio-2017, database-project

I have a .net Core app in VS2017 that also has a Database Project in the solution as well.

I want to set up continuous integration within Visual Studio Team Services to Build and Publish both the app and the database project. I have been able to get either the database project or app in the Publish Artifacts, but can't get them both at the same time. I am assuming I have set up my paths up wrong, but I have not had an luck with any of the combinations I have tried and there is very little documentation that I can find on having both an .net core app and a database project build and deploy together. How do I build and publish both the .net core app and the database project together in VSTS?

Below is the current set up I have in VSTS for the Build. I currently was trying to put the database project in one folder ($(build.artifactstagingdirectory)) and the app in another folder since resulted in

[List of current steps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PQNFq.png)

Below is the output from the current setup as seen in the image above

---

Starting: Build

## ******************************************************************************

Task         : .NET Core
Description  : Build, test and publish using dotnet core command-line.
Version      : 1.0.2

## Author       : Microsoft Corporation

"C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe" build d:\a\1\s\DatabaseDeploymentTest.web\DatabaseDeploymentTest.web.csproj --configuration release
Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 15.1.1012.6693
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
  DatabaseDeploymentTest.web -> d:\a\1\s\DatabaseDeploymentTest.web\bin\release\netcoreapp1.1\DatabaseDeploymentTest.web.dll
Build succeeded.
    0 Warning(s)
    0 Error(s)
Time Elapsed 00:00:07.50

---

Finishing: Build

---

---

Starting: Build solution **/*.sln

## ******************************************************************************

Task         : MSBuild
Description  : Build with MSBuild
Version      : 1.120.0

## Author       : Microsoft Corporation

"D:\a_tasks\MSBuild_c6c4c611-aa2e-4a33-b606-5eaba2196824\1.120.0\ps_modules\MSBuildHelpers\vswhere.exe" -version [15.0,16.0) -latest -format json
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\msbuild.exe" "d:\a\1\s\DatabaseDeploymentTest.sln" /nologo /nr:false /dl:CentralLogger,"D:\a_tasks\MSBuild_c6c4c611-aa2e-4a33-b606-5eaba2196824\1.120.0\ps_modules\MSBuildHelpers\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.MSBuild.Logger.dll";"RootDetailId=|SolutionDir=d:\a\1\s"*ForwardingLogger,"D:\a_tasks\MSBuild_c6c4c611-aa2e-4a33-b606-5eaba2196824\1.120.0\ps_modules\MSBuildHelpers\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.MSBuild.Logger.dll" /t:build /p:CmdLineInMemoryStorage=True /p:_MSDeployUserAgent="VSTS_8786b412-4ab0-4ae3-aa96-af0394363b64_build_32_835"
Building the projects in this solution one at a time. To enable parallel build, please add the "/m" switch.
Build started 8/7/2017 6:40:49 PM.
Project "d:\a\1\s\DatabaseDeploymentTest.sln" on node 1 (build target(s)).
ValidateSolutionConfiguration:
  Building solution configuration "Debug|Any CPU".
Project "d:\a\1\s\DatabaseDeploymentTest.sln" (1) is building "d:\a\1\s\DatabaseDeploymentTest\DatabaseDeploymentTest.sqlproj" (2) on node 1 (default targets).
PrepareForBuild:
  Creating directory "bin\Debug\".
  Creating directory "obj\Debug\".
CoreCompile:
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\Roslyn\csc.exe /noconfig /nowarn:1701,1702 /nostdlib+ /errorreport:prompt /warn:4 /define:DEBUG;TRACE /highentropyva+ /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.5.2\mscorlib.dll" /debug+ /debug:full /optimize- /out:obj\Debug\DatabaseDeploymentTest.dll /ruleset:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Team Tools\Static Analysis Tools\Rule Sets\MinimumRecommendedRules.ruleset" /subsystemversion:6.00 /target:library /warnaserror- /utf8output "d:\a_temp.NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2.SqlClrAttributes.cs"
  Using shared compilation with compiler from directory: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\Roslyn
SqlBuild:
  Creating a model to represent the project...
  Loading project references...
  Loading project files...
  Building the project model and resolving object interdependencies...
  Validating the project model...
  Writing model to d:\a\1\s\DatabaseDeploymentTest\obj\Debug\Model.xml...
DatabaseDeploymentTest\dbo\Stored Procedures\LoadEmployees.sql(1,1): Warning SQL71558: The object reference [dbo].[Employees].[HKSEmployeeId] differs only by case from the object definition [dbo].[Employees].[HKSEmployeeID].
d:\a\1\s\DatabaseDeploymentTest\dbo\Stored Procedures\LoadEmployees.sql(1,1,1,1): Build warning SQL71558: The object reference [dbo].[Employees].[HKSEmployeeId] differs only by case from the object definition [dbo].[Employees].[HKSEmployeeID]. [d:\a\1\s\DatabaseDeploymentTest\DatabaseDeploymentTest.sqlproj]
CopyFilesToOutputDirectory:
  Copying file from "obj\Debug\DatabaseDeploymentTest.dll" to "bin\Debug\DatabaseDeploymentTest.dll".
  DatabaseDeploymentTest -> d:\a\1\s\DatabaseDeploymentTest\bin\Debug\DatabaseDeploymentTest.dll
  Copying file from "obj\Debug\DatabaseDeploymentTest.pdb" to "bin\Debug\DatabaseDeploymentTest.pdb".
SqlPrepareForRun:
  DatabaseDeploymentTest -> d:\a\1\s\DatabaseDeploymentTest\bin\Debug\DatabaseDeploymentTest.dacpac
Done Building Project "d:\a\1\s\DatabaseDeploymentTest\DatabaseDeploymentTest.sqlproj" (default targets).
Project "d:\a\1\s\DatabaseDeploymentTest.sln" (1) is building "d:\a\1\s\DatabaseDeploymentTest.web\DatabaseDeploymentTest.web.csproj" (3) on node 1 (default targets).
PrepareForBuild:
  Creating directory "bin\Debug\netcoreapp1.1\".
  Creating directory "obj\Debug\netcoreapp1.1\".
PreComputeCompileTypeScript:
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\2.2\tsc.exe  --noEmitOnError --listEmittedFiles
CompileTypeScript:
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\2.2\tsc.exe  --noEmitOnError --listEmittedFiles
GenerateTargetFrameworkMonikerAttribute:
Skipping target "GenerateTargetFrameworkMonikerAttribute" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
CoreCompile:
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\Roslyn\csc.exe /noconfig /unsafe- /checked- /nowarn:1701,1702,1705 /nostdlib+ /errorreport:prompt /warn:4 /define:TRACE;DEBUG;NETCOREAPP1_1 /reference:C:\Users\buildguest.nuget\packages\microsoft.applicationinsights.aspnetcore\2.0.0\lib\netstandard1.6\Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore.dll /reference:C:\Users\buildguest.nuget\packages\microsoft.applicationinsights\2.2.0\lib\netstandard1.5\Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.dll /reference:C:\Users\buildguest.nuget\packages\microsoft.aspnetcore.antiforgery\1.1.1\lib\netstandard1.3\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery.dll /reference:C:\Users\buildguest.nuget\packages\microsoft.aspnetcore.authorization\1.1.1\lib\netstandard1.3\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.dll /reference:C:\Users\buildguest.nuget\packages\microsoft.aspnetcore.cors\1.1.1\lib\netstandard1.3\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors.dll /reference:C:\Users\buildguest.nuget\packages\microsoft.aspnetcore.cryptography.internal\1....
  Using shared compilation with compiler from directory: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\Roslyn
GetTypeScriptCopyToOutputDirectoryItems:
  Adding items with BuildAction=TypeScriptCompile to the same collections that will be populated (with items of other BuildActions) by the GetCopyToOutputDirectoryItems target
CopyFilesToOutputDirectory:
  Copying file from "obj\Debug\netcoreapp1.1\DatabaseDeploymentTest.web.dll" to "bin\Debug\netcoreapp1.1\DatabaseDeploymentTest.web.dll".
  DatabaseDeploymentTest.web -> d:\a\1\s\DatabaseDeploymentTest.web\bin\Debug\netcoreapp1.1\DatabaseDeploymentTest.web.dll
  Copying file from "obj\Debug\netcoreapp1.1\DatabaseDeploymentTest.web.pdb" to "bin\Debug\netcoreapp1.1\DatabaseDeploymentTest.web.pdb".
Done Building Project "d:\a\1\s\DatabaseDeploymentTest.web\DatabaseDeploymentTest.web.csproj" (default targets).
Done Building Project "d:\a\1\s\DatabaseDeploymentTest.sln" (build target(s)).
Build succeeded.
"d:\a\1\s\DatabaseDeploymentTest.sln" (build target) (1) ->
"d:\a\1\s\DatabaseDeploymentTest\DatabaseDeploymentTest.sqlproj" (default target) (2) ->
(SqlBuild target) -> 
  d:\a\1\s\DatabaseDeploymentTest\dbo\Stored Procedures\LoadEmployees.sql(1,1,1,1): Build warning SQL71558: The object reference [dbo].[Employees].[HKSEmployeeId] differs only by case from the object definition [dbo].[Employees].[HKSEmployeeID]. [d:\a\1\s\DatabaseDeploymentTest\DatabaseDeploymentTest.sqlproj]
    1 Warning(s)
    0 Error(s)
Time Elapsed 00:00:12.94

---

Finishing: Build solution **/*.sln

---

---

Starting: Copy Files to: $(build.artifactstagingdirectory)

## ******************************************************************************

Task         : Copy Files
Description  : Copy files from source folder to target folder using match patterns (The match patterns will only match file paths, not folder paths)
Version      : 2.117.0

## Author       : Microsoft Corporation

found 0 files

---

Finishing: Copy Files to: $(build.artifactstagingdirectory)

---

---

Starting: Publish

## ******************************************************************************

Task         : .NET Core
Description  : Build, test and publish using dotnet core command-line.
Version      : 1.0.2

## Author       : Microsoft Corporation

"C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe" publish d:\a\1\s\DatabaseDeploymentTest.web\DatabaseDeploymentTest.web.csproj --configuration release --output d:\a\1\a\DatabaseDeploymentTest.web
Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 15.1.1012.6693
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
  DatabaseDeploymentTest.web -> d:\a\1\s\DatabaseDeploymentTest.web\bin\release\netcoreapp1.1\DatabaseDeploymentTest.web.dll

---

Finishing: Publish

---

---

Starting: Publish Artifact

## ******************************************************************************

Task         : Publish Build Artifacts
Description  : Publish Build artifacts to the server or a file share
Version      : 1.120.1

## Author       : Microsoft Corporation

---

Async Command Start: Upload Artifact

---

Uploading 1 files
File upload succeed.
Upload 'd:\a\1\a' to file container: '#/677588/DatabaseDeploymentTest'
Associated artifact 724 with build 835

---

Async Command End: Upload Artifact

---

---

Finishing: Publish Artifact

---

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specify `$(build.sourcesdirectory)` in **Source Folder** and `**\*.dacpac` in **Contents** of Copy files task.

Comment: This worked great! 

I did run into an issue with my release once I got the build working right.

I got the following error on the "Execute Azure SQL : DacpacTask" task.
I am using the server admin login on both the task and in the publish profile I am referencing. Do you know what causes this? 

Unable to connect to master or target server 'databasedeploymenttest-staging'. You must have a user with the same password in master or target server 'databasedeploymenttest-staging'.

Comment: nvm. I forgot that I changed the password for the admin account.